# how can I tune the locale format of the calendar date LyX export pdflatex automatically generates and inserts?

Tags: pdftex, lyx, languages, date, locale

I'm using LyX (version 2.3.7 under MacOS 13.5.2) to generate small documents containing mostly math (homework assignments for a university course) and am generally very impressed with the power, stability, and ease-of-use of this approach.

My course is in German, I typically install and use software in English. When I generate PDF output (using Export/pdflatex) the current calendar date is automatically inserted near the top, below the title lines and above the rest of my content. This is a convenient feature I generally approve of. The only cosmetic problem is the date is printed in an English format: October 17, 2023 (in this setting I'd prefer a German format, e.g. 17.10.2023.)

I assume the format can be tuned somewhere, but I haven't found where. I've searched under LyX/Preferences and under Document/Settings, but haven't found anything related to this.

I also searched the web and this site without finding any hints.

I'd be grateful for advice on how to adjust this.

Comment: Replace the language of the document to German in `Document->Settings->Language->Language`

Comment: And if you want to suppress the date you can do that by checking the box `Suppress default date on front page` in `Document->Settings->Document Class`.

Comment: Many thanks. That does it!

Comment: @UdiFogiel I suggest you copy/paste your comments as an answer so we get this out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually language packages modify the date format to the appropriate one, thus specifying the correct language in `Document->Settings->Language->Language` should modify the date to the correct format.

Additionally, you can suppress by checking the box `Suppress default date on front page` in `Document->Settings->Document Class`.